# Problem with "in a row"

Tags: questions

Is it correct to turn the sentence "He'll be her six husband" into a question" Which husband of hers in a row will he be?"
Any other alternatives?
Best wishes,
Boguslaw

Comment: 'How many husbands will that make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a row of six husbands, what will be his position as her husband"
Note that the expression in the original question should be "sixth husband" and not "six husband".